How to Create a Dynamic Cropping Tool with React Konva That Greys Out the Non-Cropped Area
I'm working on an image editing application using React Konva and have encountered a challenge in implementing a dynamic cropping tool. My goal is to allow users to select a crop area on an image, which should remain clear and visible, while the rest of the image outside this selected area becomes greyed out. This visual feedback is crucial for indicating the area of the image that will be cropped.
Here's the simplified structure of my current setup:
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Stage, Layer, Image as KonvaImage, Rect, Transformer } from 'react-konva';
import useImage from 'use-image';

export default function Editor({ imageUrl }) {
  const [image] = useImage(imageUrl);
  const [crop, setCrop] = useState({ x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 150 });
  const rectRef = useRef(null);
  const transformerRef = useRef(null);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

  // Overlay and crop rectangle setup omitted for brevity

  return (
    <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
      <Layer>
        {image && (
          <>
            <KonvaImage image={image} />
            {/* Intent: Grey out area outside this Rect */}
            <Rect
              ref={rectRef}
              {...crop}
              draggable
              onDragEnd={...}
              onTransformEnd={...}
              onClick={() => setSelected(!selected)}
            />
            {selected && <Transformer ref={transformerRef} />}
          </>
        )}
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
}

I've tried using a combination of Rect components to create a semi-transparent overlay that covers the whole image, intending to "cut out" the crop area using the globalCompositeOperation set to 'destination-out'. However, this hasn't worked as expected, possibly due to my misunderstanding of how globalCompositeOperation works with layers or shapes in React Konva.
Questions:

How can I effectively grey out the non-cropped area while keeping the selected crop area clear and visible?
Is there a more straightforward or efficient approach in React Konva to achieve this dynamic cropping tool's visual effect?
Could my issue be related to how I'm using globalCompositeOperation, or is it more about the order and composition of Konva layers and shapes?

Any guidance, code examples, or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated. I'm open to adjusting my approach if there's a better way to achieve this effect.
Edit
This demo shows what I'd like to do.
